# Why can't I start two servers in the same Go project?

Tags: go, go-gin, grpc-go

I am a new Go developer and I am trying to build a single project that has both a gRPC server and a Gin HTTP server. This is what my code roughly looks like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {
    startGRPCServer()
    startHTTPServer()
}

func startGRPCServer() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not attach listener to port: %v", err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    if err := s.Serve(listener); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not start grpc server: %v", err)
    }
}

func startHTTPServer() {
    g := gin.Default()

    if err := g.Run(":8000"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not start http server: %v", err)
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, only the gRPC server starts. The `startHTTPServer()` function doesn't even get invoked. When I switch the order of the calls (move `startHTTPServer()` above `startGRPCServer()`), the `startGRPCServer()` function never gets called. Why does this happen? How can I fix this so that both functions get called and both servers run?

Comment: You can start as many servers as you want, but both of your `start*` functions are blocking, so you'll need to run them both in separate goroutines (and keep `main` from returning early, typically by waiting on a signal like `SIGTERM`).

Comment: Change `startGRPCServer()` to [`go startGRPCServer()`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) and keep the rest as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The startGRPCServer function blocks on running the grpc server. Run the GRPC server in a goroutine so that startGRPCServer returns.

```
func startGRPCServer() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not attach listener to port: %v", err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    go func() {
        if err := s.Serve(listener); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not start grpc server: %v", err)
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Are there any performance issues that I need to be worried about if I run the gRPC server inside a goroutine?

Comment: The one extra goroutine does not create any performance issues.